# Hooking feature reciever issue

Tags: deployment, feature-activation, feature-receiver

I have invalidly hooked feature reciever. Feature has two configuration files The first, SharePoint looks like this:

```
< feature xmlns:dm0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/DslTools/Core" Id="94bb0bbe-ba87-4ff4-accd-6cd429b337ad" featureId="94bb0bbe-ba87-4ff4-accd-6cd429b337ad" imageUrl="" solutionId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" title="Alokacie" version="" deploymentPath="$SharePoint.Project.FileNameWithoutExtension$_$SharePoint.Feature.FileNameWithoutExtension$" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/SharePointTools/FeatureModel">
  < projectItems>
    < projectItemReference itemId="84752a89-37b6-401d-9353-034b10f3671c" />
    < projectItemReference itemId="c829a4dc-2469-4ab5-a3e1-4a3bfce1c552" />
  < /projectItems>
< /feature>
```

and the second one, feature template:

```
< Feature ReceiverAssembly="FeatureBuilder, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cf0c34879675fa15" ReceiverClass="FeatureBuilder.FeatureReciever" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
< /Feature>
```

When I try to register eventhandler in the first one (feature file) nothing happend. Even in SharePointManager are empty properties: ReceiverAssembly, ReceiverClass. Now I'm able to deploy without problems. When I register eventhandler in the second one, as you can see above, SharePointManager after failed deployment shows that ReceiverAssembly and Class is what I expect. But deployment fails due to error:

> "Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Expression
>   must evaluate to a node-set."

Receiver method:

```
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
        var service = SPWebService.ContentService;
        var myModification = new SPWebConfigModification();
        myModification.Path = "configuration/AplikaceRoly";
        myModification.Name = "add[@name=Name]";
        myModification.Sequence = 0;
        myModification.Owner = "NESS";
        myModification.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
        myModification.Value = "<add key='sth' value='Sth'/>";
        service.WebConfigModifications.Add(myModification);

        service.ApplyWebConfigModifications();
        service.Update();
```

When I remove ReceiverClass nad ReceiverAssembly attributes I can deploy without problems again.

Have somebody idea what's wrong? I can't find simmilar problems on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `configuration/AplikaceRoly` exist?

Otherwise you need to create if before your child node:

```
var myModification1 = new SPWebConfigModification("AplikaceRoly", "configuration");
myModification1.Value = "AplikaceRoly";
myModification1.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureSection;
myModification1.Sequence = 0;
webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(myModification1);
```

Comment: yes, it exists. Even when I let this method empty, I'm still getting this error => I guess it has nothing with receiver. Just when I add attribute ReceiverClass , ReceiverAssembly , deployment fails with this error.

Comment: How do you deploy? If from PowerShell/VS remember to exit/relaunch it whenever you change a FeatureReceiver dll.

Comment: Oh yeah, bless you man. So that means, this part of code "myModification.Path = "configuration/AplikaceRoly";"
is problem. But I'm sure that this node exists there. I've tried with XPath online tester , and it found that node. On the other side, I was testing web config in target server in %RootDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\web.config ... Application uses this web.config but I'm pretty not sure whether code above is changing this config...